Milne Exercise 3-3(d) on Algebraic Group
Let $(A, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$ be a finitely generated commutative Hopf algebra over a field $k$. The exercises asks us to prove that
$$a \otimes b \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \Delta(b): A \otimes A \to A \otimes A$$
is a $k$-algebra homomorphism by interpreting it as a statement about algebraic groups. However, I don't see a good way to do it.
Let $(G, m, e, \operatorname{inv}) = \operatorname{mSpec} (A, \Delta, \epsilon, S)$ be the algebraic group corresponding to $A$. Then the exercise can be done in two parts: translating the map to a map $G \times G \to G \times G$, and then checking that it is a (honest) group homomorphism on $R$-points. Since the map is essentially the composition
$$A \otimes A \xrightarrow{f \otimes \Delta} A \otimes A \otimes A \otimes A \xrightarrow{\mu_{A \otimes A}} A \otimes A$$
$$a \otimes b \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \otimes \Delta(b) \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \Delta(b)$$
My naive guess is that we should get the map
$$G \times G \to G \times G \times G \times G \to G \times G$$
where the first is (given on $R$-points by) the diagonal map $(g,h) \mapsto (g,h,g,h)$ and the second is $\operatorname{pr}_1 \times m$. The resulting map on $R$-point gives $(g,h) \mapsto (g,gh)$, which is not a group homomorphism unless $G(R)$ is abelian, but this requires the Hopf algebra to be cocommutative, which is not the case. Where did my thought process went wrong, and what should be the correct map?

You only need to find a morphism of schemes between these group schemes. This is sufficient to define a corresponding algebra homomorphism. It is not claimed that this is a homomorphism of Hopf algebras.
But it's actually more simple, without using the hint. The unit $e: k \to A$ is an algebra homomorphism, hence $A \otimes e: A \to A \otimes A$, $a \mapsto a \otimes 1$ as well. The comultiplication $\Delta : A \to A \otimes A$ is an algebra homomorphism as well. Finally, we know that the tensor product of algebras provides the coproduct in the category of commutative algebras. Hence, $a \otimes b \mapsto (a \otimes 1) \cdot \Delta(b)$ defines an algebra homomorphism.
